# Can soil moisture values be calculated from only land surface temperature?

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics, satellite

I'm working on a project that requires me to calculate soil moisture values at specific points under future climate scenarios. I have soil moisture values for the points from historical periods and the associated land surface temperature at each point, but need soil moisture values at those points under nine potential future climate conditions. Is there a way to estimate the soil moisture just using temperature (is there a significant relationship between the two variables, enough to predict future soil moisture content from predicted temperature)?

Again, the only variable I am looking to use to derive soil moisture values is land surface temperature. I have fields with past soil moisture and temperature at certain lat/long points. I also have a raster layer with projected temperature under a future climate scenario. Is there a way to estimate a relationship between the historical LST and soil moisture in order to predict future soil moisture based on the future temperature raster layer?